# How to stop screen from dimming when watching video?

Tags: video, system-settings, display

After a while being inactive with the mouse or keyboard, the macbook will dim my screen to save battery. I know I can expand the delay before it will dim in the system preferences, but are there any way of automatically disable it when watching video?

It's quite annoying having to touch the mouse every few minutes when watching a movie...

Comment: What kind of video are you talking about (.avi or web)? Using Quicktime, if I put the movie in fullscreen, it no longer dim the screen. I haven't tested with other player.

Comment: The video that nudged me into writing this question, was the keynote published yesterday. I would guess that it used Quicktime?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a software like [Caffeine](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/) to easily achieve your need :

*Caffeine is a tiny program that puts an icon in the right side of your menu bar. Click it to prevent your Mac from automatically going to sleep, dimming the screen or starting screen savers. Click it again to go back. Right-click (or ⌘-click) the icon to show the menu.*

Comment: I think I liked this one better. Will try for a while. Thanks ;-)

Comment: +1 I downloaded this app (if you can call it that) last night. Its pretty nifty.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jiggler](http://www.sticksoftware.com/software/Jiggler.html)

Jiggler will "jiggle" the mouse transparently to stop dimming or other "sleep" actions. No installation, no ktext loading. Just a little jiggle every 20 sec or so.

I find it absolutely indespensible for watching Hulu movies, videos, or any other action where the screen should stay lit, but I don't want to tinker with the energy saver settings.

[image: Jiggler]

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you use your laptop when you are watching the movie:)

You can adjust settings separately for Power adapter or Battery

system preferences>Energy Saver>Put the display(s) to sleep when the computer is inactive for...
But make sure in Options section>other Options uncheck box "Automatically reduce the brightness of display before display sleep"

Or use caffeine software:)